# web.py seeother() not functioning as expected

Tags: python, web.py

I'm new to web.py. Trying to setup redirection as explained in the documentation. However, when I send a curl request for `localhost:8080/health/` the application returns `None` instead of the `HAPPY`

```
import web

urls = (
        #url, #class_name
        '/', 'index',
        '/(.*)/', 'redirect',   # match localhost:port/somepath/
        '/health', 'health'
)


class index:
    def GET(self):
        return 'Hello World!'

# this is faulty and not redirecting as expected
class redirect:
    def GET(self, path):
        web.seeother('/' + path)

class health:
    def GET(self):
        return "HAPPY"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to have `raise` in front of `web.seeother(...)`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: raise would not return a response to the user.

Comment: That's what the [documentation](https://webpy.org/cookbook/redirect+seeother) says to do.  I assume the web.py framework has some way of catching the `raise` exception and handling it appropriately...

Comment: Nope. That did not help. Are you able to solve the issue from your end by adding raise?

Comment: What do you mean "solve the issue from your end"?  I do not have an issue.  I do not use web.py at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your python code is fine. The problem is your use of curl.

By default, curl won't follow redirects unless instructed. Add the -L option and you're good to go.

```
$ curl -L http://localhost:8080/health
HAPPY
```

Comment: thanks for your kindness in testing it!